# How do you clear menu caches programmatically?

Tags: 8, caching, navigation

I am developing a custom module. In this module, I want to delete menu caches programmatically. For this, I have used

```
\Drupal::cache('menu')->invalidateAll(); // for clearing the menu cache      
\Drupal::service('plugin.manager.menu.link')->rebuild(); // rebuild the menu
```

But somehow, menu cache seems not being cleared and still the old menu is being displayed. How can I force Drupal to have my updated menu being displayed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Menu's are displayed via blocks.  You will probably have to clear the block render cache as well.

```
\Drupal::cache('block')->invalidateAll();
```

Comment: Getting error message = You have requested a non-existent service "cache.block". 
I'm not certain what would be correct. I see "block" and "menu link" items in the cache_entity table, so that might be the correct path to take.