# How can I invalidate the entire cache when saving menu item?

Tags: hooks, navigation, caching, 10

I use the [Simplify Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplify_menu) module. Since changes in the menu are not applied, I would like to clear the entire cache.
Unfortunately the following code does not work

```
function MODULE_menu_link_content_update(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity)
{
        if ($entity->menu_name->value === 'main') {
            \Drupal::cache()->invalidateAll();
        }
}
```

does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you clear menu caches programmatically?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/246450/how-do-you-clear-menu-caches-programmatically)

Comment: thanks! but not really. the hook MODULE_menu_link_content_update does not seem to be called when a menu item is updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Simplify Menu module has the problem that it doesn't transport cache metadata and a code like `\Drupal::cache()->invalidateAll()` doesn't exist.

You can add the most important cache tag to the Twig template yourself because you know the menu name:

```
{{ {'#cache': {'tags': ['config:system.menu.main']}} }}
```

Then changes in the `main` menu configuration will trigger a cache invalidation of the template automatically.

After you've added the cache tag to the Twig template it's possible to use it for menu content as well. The hook mentioned in the question can target it like this:

```
\Drupal::service('cache_tags.invalidator')->invalidateTags(['config:system.menu.main']);
```

This cache tag is the most important one and you will see a much better cache handling. However, there is a lot more cache metadata in menus, for example cache contexts for access handling, so this module should be used only for really simple menus.

### Background info

For arrays Twig `{{ }}` is the same as PHP `render()`, which bubbles up metadata in contrast to renderPlain(). You use render() in the theming level (templates and preprocess hooks) when there is a page render stack (Drupal term *render context* not to be confused with *cache context*). Bubbleable metadata is `#cache` and `#attached` in a render array.

For example the core Twig function

```
{{ attach_library('core/drupal.dialog.ajax') }}
```

runs PHP:

```
  public function attachLibrary($library) {
    assert(is_string($library), 'Argument must be a string.');

    // Use Renderer::render() on a temporary render array to get additional
    // bubbleable metadata on the render stack.
    $template_attached = ['#attached' => ['library' => [$library]]];
    $this->renderer->render($template_attached);
  }
```

and could be replaced in Twig with the same result:

```
{{ {'#attached': {'library': ['core/drupal.dialog.ajax']}} }}
```

For #cache metadata you have to use the second method as there is no specific Twig function in core. Or the contrib module could bubble up the cache tag already when preparing the menu tree because Twig functions are always in a render stack.

Comment: `{{ {'#cache': {'tags': ['config:system.menu.main']}} }}`- wow thats neat, did not know you can create a render array only for caches on the fly in Twig, without preprocessing. So you basically can add any arbitrary cache tag or cache context inline in any Twig template and it will bubble upwards?

Comment: Yes, there are also Twig extensions just bubbling up metadata because Twig templates are always rendered inside of a cache context. For example core TwigExtension::attachLibrary.

Comment: Wow, so simple. I'm a bit surprised that I can add the cache tag in the Twig template. But that's great.

Answer (score 1):

[`\Drupal::cache()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3Acache/10)`->invalidateAll()` does not invalidate the content of all the cache bins; it just invalidates the content of the *cache.default* bin.

The Workspaces module uses [`workspaces_menu_link_content_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21workspaces%21workspaces.module/function/workspaces_menu_link_content_update/10) to invalidate the menu cache. I would use similar code.

```php
function mymodule_menu_link_content_update(EntityInterface $entity) {
  if ($entity->getMenuName() === 'main') {
    $cache_tags = Cache::buildTags('config:system.menu', ['main'], '.');
    \Drupal::service('cache_tags.invalidator')->invalidateTags($cache_tags);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the second part of my answer. This hook only works after you've added the tag to the twig template. I've only included the hook because it was mentioned in the question. I'm not sure this hook is even necessary, there is already a lot of invalidating happening when updating menus and this specific workspace code would target our template if it is tagged properly as well.

Comment: Your answer does not say that the *Workspaces* module uses `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update()` to clear the cache. It also says that *code like `\Drupal::cache()->invalidateAll()` doesn't exist* without saying what exactly it would do. (Yes, it is perfectly correct code, but it does not do what the OP probably thinks it does.)